# Is it possible to connect to remote device to android studio and xcode?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

My client's app is crashed. That crash is a device-specific issue and his device is a Chinese device. I want to log that device into my laptop and testing. Is there any way to connect his device to my laptop(android studio and xcode)?

Answer (score 0):

You cant connect remote devices.
You can try Firebase Crashlytics to report and identify crashes
https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics